# can't get subquery inside CONCAT to work

Tags: mysql

I have this code:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
  CONCAT( 
   DATE_FORMAT(je.date_entered, '%m/%d/%Y - %h:%i%p'), 
   ' by ', 
   '\n', 
   REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
     REPLACE(
      REPLACE(
       REPLACE(je.description, '<br />', '\n'), 
      '&#039;', '\''), 
     '&quot;', '"'), 
    '&lt;', '<'), 
   '&gt;', '>')
  ), 
  '\n\n' ORDER BY je.date_entered DESC SEPARATOR ''
) AS enteries
```

It works fine.  When I add this subquery:

```
' by ', (SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE id = je.created_by),
```

resulting in this Group Concat:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(
 CONCAT(
  DATE_FORMAT(je.date_entered, '%m/%d/%Y - %h:%i%p'), 
  ' by ', 
  (SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE id = je.created_by), 
  '\n',   
  REPLACE(
   REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
     REPLACE(
      REPLACE(je.description, '<br />', '\n'), 
     '&#039;', '\''), 
    '&quot;', '"'), 
   '&lt;', '<'), 
  '&gt;', '>')
 ), 
 '\n\n' ORDER BY je.date_entered DESC SEPARATOR '')
AS enteries
```

it breaks the whole dang thing, causing no errors, but just returning null.

This may look hairy and tangled but I don't have the option to put everything together in php -- it has to all be done in mysql during the selection process.

p.s. I didn't post the enter query because it is ridiculously long BUT I can if you want me to.

Comment: The dumb question: for all cases of je.created_by there is a valid user in the users table?  Meaning, never a NULL created_by or out of range of the index value?

Comment: Regarding the p.s.  Thanks, but the part posted is ridiculous enough as it is :)

Comment: yes ... thats what i initially thought was maybe je.created_by contacted nothing BUT it does contain the value... when i run ---- GROUP_CONCAT(je.created_by), '\n\n' ORDER BY je.date_entered DESC SEPARATOR '') AS enteries ---- it returns the correct values.

Comment: LOL yea the rest of the query doesn't look as bad as this... this is just gathering all the entries and formatting them into one value the rest of the query, although long, is simpler :P

Comment: @Matt.... no there are only 3 entries and all 3 times it returns the correct value .. which for my testing purposes is 1

Comment: @Banning: Probably not the answer to your problem, but you might want to add `LIMIT 1` to your subquery to ensure that you only get one result.

Comment: @Travesty3 Good call, just tried it though and it still returns null

Comment: @Banning: For debugging, perhaps try hard-coding a value in place of `je.created_by`. I'm not sure you can reference a column from the outer query in your subquery. You may have to do some other type of joining, or perhaps your entire query might need some restructuring. I ran into a problem like this a LONG time ago and for the life of me, can't remember how I solved it.

Comment: @Travesty3 GREAT IDEA.. .just tried running plain ol' SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE id = 1 and it returned 3 results NONE of which is what i was expecting... looks like i finally have some more to look into here thanks guys i'll be back

Comment: ok figured out what the deal was... first_name was returning and null value. Apparently this user only has their last_name entered. So it looks like my code was right just the data was good.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final, working solution:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(je.date_entered, '%m/%d/%Y - %h:%i%p'), ' by ', IF((SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE id LIKE je.created_by) IS NULL, '', (SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE id LIKE je.created_by)), ' ', IF((SELECT last_name FROM users WHERE id LIKE je.created_by) IS NULL, '', (SELECT last_name FROM users WHERE id LIKE je.created_by)), '\n', REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(je.description, '<br />', '\n'), '&#039;', '\''), '&quot;', '"'), '&lt;', '<'), '&gt;', '>')), '\n\n' ORDER BY je.date_entered DESC SEPARATOR '') AS enteries
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a subquery inside `group_concat` and `concat`, they will return:

- NULL if the subquery returns 0 rows OR a NULL value
- something (presumably good) if the subquery returns 1 row
- an error (1242) if the subquery returns more than one row

Presumably your subquery didn't return any rows or returned a NULL value.

Comment: yea my subquery returned a row it just returned a row with NULL... also it was returned 3 rows... so i had to change "= je.created_by" to "LIKE je.created_by"